# Why is numpy's default value for this ndarray equal to a relatively large number and not ~0.0?

Tags: python, numpy

In my PyCharm IDE if I open up a Python Console (Interpreter) and attempt to instantiate a `numpy.ndarray` with initial shape `[1]` I get the following result:

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 8.4.0
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
import numpy as np
np.ndarray([1])
Out[3]: array([0.0078125])
```

This default value seems relatively (>>) larger than I expected. I would expect something close to `0.0` or essentially `0.0` (i.e. `1.234e+178`). Given it's the size of the value it does not seem to be some sort of rounding error.

[Checking the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) it looks like users are not really intended to make an instance of `ndarray` directly, but rather rely on `array`. Though, the documentation even provides an example of instantiating a `(2, 2)` shaped array.

---

Relatedly interesting, it seems that the default value seems to change "suddenly" after instantiating different sized `ndarray`. If I keep playing around in the same terminal from above I get the following behavior

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 8.4.0
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
import numpy as np
np.ndarray([1])
Out[3]: array([0.0078125])
np.ndarray([1, 2])
Out[4]: array([[1.02724393e-188, 6.85721358e+215]])
np.ndarray(1)
Out[5]: array([6.85721358e+215])
np.ndarray([1])
Out[6]: array([6.85721358e+215])
```

Various online Python interactive terminals produce the same behavior.

---

**Why is the default value for `numpy.ndarray([1])` equal to such a large value?**

Is it that the default value of the `buffer` is somehow equal to this value "by default" for a size `(1)` array?..

Note: `1/128 = 0.0078125`

Comment: Yes. This is a cheap instantiation method. It's really meant for use if you know you're going to be initializing every value in the array yourself before ever reading them.

Comment: Also, it's basically reading junk from the memory location it assigns to the array so it can be anything really.

Comment: I don't think it's reading junk, it seems to be reading the same value. I get the same behavior across two PCs and a few online interpreters. // https://www.online-python.com/YyIF3pSci9

Comment: It is reading a buffer. I suspect it's reading a static buffer which is some memory offset somewhere in memory. It's copying the bytes from that buffer into the array so it could be picking the same spot to copy from and it could be somewhere in the program memory stack which could be the same if the program is recently instantiated (not many changes made to the memory yet). This is just me guessing. I haven't studied the C code which makes the array.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.ndarray([1])` is interpreted as an **empty array** with a shape of `(1,)` (ie. 1D array of size 1). There is **no default value**. This means neither Numpy nor the operating system initialize the array. As a result the array can contains non-zero values. In practice, it is often 0 because most operating systems zeroize memory areas for security reasons (you generally do not want data from another process to leak like passwords from your browser). Note however that the allocator of CPython is free to recycle previously allocated memory now freed. Some values are close to zeros because they are small integers that are interpreted as small floating-point numbers (most integers tends to be small in programs). When exponent bits are set, the resulting floating-point value can be big like in your example. Relying on this value is not a good idea as it results in an undefined behaviour (the value can be a silent NaN or even a signalling NaN possibly unhandled interruptions). Use `np.zeros` instead.

Comment: Any idea why it seems to "always" be equal to 1/128?

Comment: This is dependent of past allocation made by CPython because of the way the internal allocator works. It has a quite deterministic behaviour (but chaotic) so the result can be always the same for the same version of CPython and Numpy. That being said, this can change with another version. Allocating new array can also change the value (and often does). As for the 1/128, this is 0b0011111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in binary so mainly zeros but not fully.

Comment: It seems this is where the value is actually set ( https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c2ddceb01a28243db684b537e518c022e76e4d7a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L783 ) // But I'd have to dig further into `PyDataMem_UserNEW_ZEROED` I think.

Comment: This function is not called during the execution of `np.ndarray([1])`. You can check that with a debugger (like GDB, which I did to be sure). In fact, `PyArray_NewFromDescr_int` is called but `zeroed` is 0 and `descr` is not set to `NPY_NEEDS_INIT`. Instead, `PyDataMem_UserNEW` is called and this one just use `malloc` of the allocation handler with *no zero initialization* and the item value is the one got from the allocator that recycle memory, exactly as stated in the answer.